# mysqlprofileprovider can't connect

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, mysql-connector

Hello I've googled but could not find any solution, unfortunately.

I've set up my mysqlprovider like so:

```
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{
    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return base["FirstName"] as string; }
        set { base["FirstName"] = value; }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return base["LastName"] as string; }
        set { base["LastName"] = value; }
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public String test { get; set; }

    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
    {
        return Create(username) as UserProfile;
    }

    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile()
    {
        return Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName) as UserProfile;
    }
}
```

And the web.config part:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLServer" connectionString="Pooling=false;data source=xxx;Persist Security Info=false;database=xx;user id=xx;password=xx;Pooling=false" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<profile inherits="SA2.Infrastructure.BO.Security.UserProfile" defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" /></providers>
</profile>
```

And I am trying to create a profile like so:

```
UserProfile lProfile = (UserProfile)SA2.Infrastructure.BO.Security.UserProfile.Create(User.Identity.Name);
lProfile.test = "Wurstsalat";
lProfile.Save();
```

It doesn't seem to connect to the database at all. I am not getting an exceptions or anthing. I am kind of lost here..